# How to manually make object mapping in RestKit?

Tags: restkit

I have an response object on both client and server side like this:

Client side :

```
//BaseResponse.h
@interface BaseResponse : NSObject{
    NSString *code;
    NSString *message;
    NSObject *responseObject;
}
+(RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping;

//BaseResponse.m
+(RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping{
    RKObjectMapping *baseResponseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[BaseResponse class]];
    [baseResponseMapping mapKeyPath:@"code" toAttribute:@"code"];
    [baseResponseMapping mapKeyPath:@"message" toAttribute:@"message"];
    [baseResponseMapping mapKeyPath:@"responseObject" toAttribute:@"responseObject"];

    return baseResponseMapping;
}
```

Server side :

```
public class BaseResponse {
   private String code; 
   private String message;  
   private Object responseObject;
...
}
```

When i call the restful web service from ios, it returns a BaseResponse object. But the responseObject in BaseResponse can be vary according to web service method. So i did it Object on server side and client side.

So my question is this: How could i make object mapping manually in restkit after `- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response` method or `- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects` method called.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is this

```
...
[objectManager postObject:nil path:path parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    BaseResponse *response = (BaseResponse *)[[result array] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSError *error = nil;
    AppVersion *appVersion = [[AppVersion alloc]init];
    RKMappingOperation *operation = [[RKMappingOperation alloc]
                                                 initWithSourceObject:response.responseObject destinationObject:appVersion mapping:[AppVersion objectMapping] ];

    BOOL success = [operation performMapping:&error];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

RESTkit actually has very good support for this. Basically you will need to have something in the response you can use to identify what kind of mapping you would like to perform.

To do this, you define your mapping as dynamic mapping, and go from there.

I could copy the example from the wiki, but that would be cheating, so I suggest you take a look at [this part of the mapping explanation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#dynamic-object-mapping).